# Moving 3D object data into separate XAML file

Tags: wpf, xaml, viewport3d

I have a XAML file of some view where a complex 3D model is defined. The problem is that the part defining the model is quite big, it has over 0.5 MB and it's really hard to browse through the file. Is there a way I can move e.g the `Model3DGroup` into another file and then include it in my main XAML file? I use a SketchUp to XAML converter which creates files with `<Model3DGroup xmlns="..." xmlns:x="...">` as their roots, so I'm almost sure it can be done in a convenient way.

My current XAML file looks like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="BigAtom.Views.WorkspaceView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestProj"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="278" d:DesignWidth="274">

    <Grid x:Name="RootVisual" Background="Beige" ClipToBounds="True">
        <Canvas Name="DrawingCanvas" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Width="0" Height="0" RenderTransform="1,0,0,-1,0,0" Margin="10">
            <Viewport3D Name="Object3D" Width="50" Height="50" Margin="-25,-25" ClipToBounds="False">
                <Viewport3D.Camera>
                    <OrthographicCamera x:Name="CamMain" Position="0 60 100" LookDirection="0 -60 -100"></OrthographicCamera>
                </Viewport3D.Camera>
                <ModelVisual3D>
                    <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                        <DirectionalLight x:Name="DirLightMain" Direction="-1,-1,-1"/>
                    </ModelVisual3D.Content>
                </ModelVisual3D>
                <ModelVisual3D x:Name="MyModel">
                    <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                        <Model3DGroup>
                            <GeometryModel3D>
                                <GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                                    <MeshGeometry3D Positions="-5.6166 10.4050 153.1136 [very long line]" TextureCoordinates="-5.616612 -10.405044  -3.582495 [very long line]" TriangleIndices="164 17 57 [very long line]"/>
                                </GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                                <GeometryModel3D.Material>
                                    <DiffuseMaterial Color="White" Brush="#ffffff"/>
                                </GeometryModel3D.Material>
                                <GeometryModel3D.BackMaterial>
                                    <DiffuseMaterial Color="White" Brush="White"/>
                                </GeometryModel3D.BackMaterial>
                            </GeometryModel3D>
                        </Model3DGroup>
                    </ModelVisual3D.Content>
                </ModelVisual3D>
            </Viewport3D>
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

and I want to achieve something like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="BigAtom.Views.WorkspaceView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestProj"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="278" d:DesignWidth="274">

    <Grid x:Name="RootVisual" Background="Beige" ClipToBounds="True">
        <Canvas Name="DrawingCanvas" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Width="0" Height="0" RenderTransform="1,0,0,-1,0,0" Margin="10">
            <Viewport3D Name="Object3D" Width="50" Height="50" Margin="-25,-25" ClipToBounds="False">
                <Viewport3D.Camera>
                    <OrthographicCamera x:Name="CamMain" Position="0 60 100" LookDirection="0 -60 -100"></OrthographicCamera>
                </Viewport3D.Camera>
                <ModelVisual3D>
                    <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                        <DirectionalLight x:Name="DirLightMain" Direction="-1,-1,-1"/>
                    </ModelVisual3D.Content>
                </ModelVisual3D>
                <ModelVisual3D x:Name="MyModel">
                    <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                        <Model3DGroup --- some kind of reference to the file which keeps the 3D model --- />
                    </ModelVisual3D.Content>
                </ModelVisual3D>
            </Viewport3D>
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**@edit**

McGarnagle's answer is generally OK, but in my case I also have some `DataTemplate` defined in my `UserControl.Resources`. Because of this, I had to create such a structure:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SomeType}" x:Key="SomeTypeTemplate">
            ....
        </DataTemplate>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
           <ResourceDictionary Source="Models.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine you should be able to use a resource dictionary for this.  Add a file, say, "Models.xaml" with the definitions:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Model3DGroup x:Key="TheModelContent">
        ...
    </Model3DGroup>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Then reference the file in your UserControl, and refer to the models using the `StaticResource` keyword:

```
<UserControl>
    <UserControl.Resources> 
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Models.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

            <!-- other resources here -->
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    ...

    <ModelVisual3D Content="{StaticResource TheModelContent}">
    ...

</UserControl>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. Visual Studio says that `x:Key` attribute is required for the `ResourceDictionary` entry. When I'm trying to give it the same key as the `Model3DGroup` in the other XAML has, R# says that the `ResourceDictionary` "hides resource from Models.xaml".

Comment: I moved `<ResourceDictionary Source="Models.xaml" />` to `Viewport3D.Resources`, now it seems to be OK without the `x:Key` (probably because I have some keyed resources in my `UserControl.Resources`). Now there's a problem with "Content="{...}", it says that an object of the type ResourceDictionary cannot be applied to a property that expects Model3D.

Comment: @PiotrK right, thanks.  I probably should have mentioned the part about needing "MergedDictionaries".